# Re-training classifier with new data produce massive class changes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost, training-data

I'm training every day XGBoost binary classifier on 150k of records.
every day, approximately 500 records added to the train set.
The test set (inference) 10M records without labels.
I noticed that two models trained in consecutive days produce fundamentally different predictions on the same records (up to 10% of the inference data).
What I have tried for now:

1. set same seeds and parameters.
2. different classifiers.

My concern is that the model is not generalize enough so there are significant changes in the daily predictions.
I would love to hear about possible ways to address this issue